# Are there nonisomorphic, finitely generated groups that surject onto each other?

Tags: group-theory

Are there nonisomorphic, finitely generated groups that surject (homomorphically) onto each other?

For example of the 'dual' problem, the free group on $2$ generators $F_2$, and the free group on $3$ generators $F_3$ inject into each other; but there is no surjection from $F_2 \to F_3$ (intuitively, if there was was, since $F_3$ surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}^3$, there would therefore be a surjection $F_2 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$, but the image of such a map could only be a $2$-dimensional sublattice of $\mathbb{Z}^3$, so we have a contradiction)

Comment: It is not possible if either of the groups is residually finite, by counting homomorphisms to finite groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's suppose that we have two nonisomorphic finitely generated groups $G$ and $H$ with surjective homomorphisms $\varphi: G \to H$ and $\psi: H \to G$. Then the first isomorphism theorem gives us
\begin{align*}
\frac{G}{\ker \varphi} &\simeq H & \frac{H}{\ker \psi} &\simeq G
\end{align*}
Since $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic, both $\ker \varphi$ and $\ker \psi$ must be nontrivial. Additionally, we can consider the composite maps $\psi \circ \varphi: G \to G$ and $\varphi \circ \psi: H \to H$. These maps, being compositions of surjections, are themselves surjective homomorphisms, and they each have nontrivial kernel. We find
\begin{align*}
\frac{G}{\ker(\psi \circ \varphi)} & \simeq G & \frac{H}{\ker(\varphi \circ \psi)} &\simeq H
\end{align*}
In other words, both $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic to nontrivial quotients of themselves. This condition is actually rather subtle. A group that is *not* isomorphic to any of its nontrivial quotients is called *Hopfian*, so what we require is a pair of finitely generated, non-Hopfian groups.

The classical example of finitely generated, non-Hopfian groups are Baumslag-Solitar groups. These groups have two generators with one relation on them. In particular, we define
$$\mathrm{BS}(m,n) = \langle a,b : a^{-1}b^m a = b^n \rangle$$
In other words, $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ is the group generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ subject to the relation that $a^{-1}b^m a = b^n$. The key result that Baumslag and Solitar proved is this:

**Theorem (Baumslag-Solitar 1962):** The group $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ is Hopfian if and only if

- $m$ and $n$ share the same prime factors **or**
- one of $m$ and $n$ divides the other.

In reference to Eric Wofsey's comment, it is a theorem of Mal'cev that all finitely generated, residually finite groups are Hopfian, so indeed we must avoid residually finite groups. If $|m|=|n|$ or $1 \in \{|m|, |n|\}$, then $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ is residually finite.

Returning to our main goal, recall that we are interested in the non-Hopfian Baumslag-Solitar groups. The simplest example of this is $\mathrm{BS}(2,3)$, which has the surjection $a \mapsto a, b \mapsto b^2$ that is not an isomorphism.

As much as I'd like to give you a nice example of groups surjecting onto each other using small Baumslag-Solitar groups, I can't seem to come up with one (I don't think such an example exists). I believe, however, that your answer lies in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5122.pdf) from 2014. Levitt defines two groups $G$ and $H$ as being *epi-equivalent* if there are surjective group homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$ and from $H$ to $G$. We have (Corollary 6.8)

**Theorem (Levitt):** Suppose that $\mathrm{BS}(m, n)$ is not Hopfian. There exist infinitely many pairwise non-isomorphic generalized Baumslag-Solitar (GBS) groups epi-equivalent to $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ if and only if $|m|$ is not prime, $|n|$ is not prime, and $\gcd(m,n) \neq 1$.

Take $G = \mathrm{BS}(4,6)$. Then this theorem asserts that there are infinitely many GBS groups epi-equivalent to $G$. Because Baumslag-Solitar and GBS groups are finitely generated, this gives the desired example of nonisomorphic, finitely generated groups that surject onto each other.

Comment: I am sorry to have closed this question as a duplicate after you have written such a detailed answer. You could consider copying this answer as an additional answer to the earlier post, which also has some helpful answers.